# How to store JSON value within azure key vault

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, key, azure-keyvault

I am straggling to understand what is the best practice to store data in json format within azure key vault or alternatively to map each single key to my "appsettings.json" files. i read a lot on that issue but i couldn't figure it out how exactly it can be done

How would i retrieve json string formatted and map it to an object or assign each key vault into my appsettings.json

This is how my json looks like.

```
{
   "Container":{
      "Machine1":{
         "url":"some address "
      }
    }
}
```

Thanks, appreciate a lots your help

Comment: Welcome! Not sure I understand your question. Key Vault is a set of key/value pairs, and you get to decide what to store as values. If you wanted to store a JSON string as a value, you could do that. Just note that storing multiple values in a single key's "value" field seems like an anti-pattern (imagine a process that's only supposed to access one particular key's value, but now has access to the entire set of your app's values).

Comment: Maybe something you'd like to have a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course, you can store JSON value to azure keyvault, follow the steps below.

1.Install the `Az` powershell module, follow this doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.8.0

2.Then use `Connect-AzAccount` to login your account, make sure your account has the correct secret permission in `Access policies` of your keyvault, if not, add it in the portal.

3.Then use the commands below(you cannot store the json value directly in the portal, the Azure Portal currently only supports single-line secret values).

```
$string = '{
   "Container":{
      "Machine1":{
         "url":"some address "
      }
    }
}'
$Secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $string -AsPlainText -Force
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name "testjson" -SecretValue $Secret
```

4.Check it in the portal -> your keyvault -> `Secrets`, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: The Azure command has since been updated to "Set-AzureKeyVaultSecret".
The attributes (-VaultName, -Name, -SecretValue) are the same

Answer (score -2):

key vault is not designed to store JSON in this manner.
Please read the following document to get a better understanding of Azure Key Vault.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview